# Alt + Up closes windows/apps instead of the default behavior

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

I'm on a ThinkPad P15 with Ubuntu 21.10, kernel `5.13.0-39-generic`. Whenever I use the shortcut `Alt` + `Up` (for instance for moving a line of code up in my IDE or when browsing up one folder) the shortcut closes the window or the application in use instead of the usual behavior I'm used to on other machines. This is regardless of what application I'm using. The strange thing is that `Alt` + `Down` works just as expected.

1. Why does this happen?
2. How do I set the shortcut to behave as expected instead?

Comment: Hello. You said other machines. Did they have the same OS? Did this machine have any custom keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: @David It's a quite universal shortcut like `Alt` + `F4` and I know this to work both on multiple Windows version as well as multiple Ubuntu versions, including the same one I currently have (but on other machines). Regarding custom keyboard shortcuts, I have not changed any of those.

Comment: Not standard behaviour: Alt+Up normally is not assigned to anything systemwide. Temporarily create a new account and log in onto that new account: does it also happen there? If yes, then it could signal a problem with the keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the keyboard layout was set differently in the BIOS config as compared to what I had on Ubuntu. Setting it correctly in BIOS solved the problem.

Comment: You can "accept" your own answer if you wish, there is no problem with that; it's done by clicking the grey arrow next to your post (turning it green).